# Linux User Creation + PHP and Email

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu

I am hosting a email server with a web interface for logging in, however I previously had no effective way of registering users with the server in order to create users to login to. Its for this reason I created a PHP system to create users, and set passwords, however having created said system, I know have a major security issue as the server will execute the script which creates the user, and then will change said users passwords. So people can change passwords of different users. I created a root safe guard for now, but I need a permanent solution to this issue in order to secure my users emails. Here is the php script, and shell script I am using to create and set user passwords.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$check=$_POST['check'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if($user!="root"){
  if($pass == $check) {

   echo exec ("sudo /root/bin/newuser.sh ".$user." ".$pass."");
   echo ("<html> <title>User Created!</title> <p><h1>Congratulation on the successful creation of your user! </h1></p><p><h1>Your login credentials are as follows:</h1></p><p><h1>Username: ".$user."</h1></p><p><h1>Password: " .$pass."</h1></p></html>");

  } else {

  echo "<html><title>Error creating account!</title><p><h1>Passwords did not match! Please <a href='index.php' reload/> this page!</h1></p></html>";
}

} else {
    echo "Stahp plox!";

  }
}
?>

<html>
  <p align="center">Magnum Dongs Email Registration</p>

  <p align="center">Username will be created as Username@magnumdongs.com, there is no need to add the @magnumdongs.com to the enter of the username you create.</p>

  <p align="center">Upon creation, you will be able to access your email through our Magnum Dongs Email Web Interface, however you will be unable to recieve email via Outlook or an open source alternative at this time.</p>

  <form method="POST" action="index.php" align="center">
   <p>Username :
     <input name="user" type="text"/>
   </p> 
   <p>Password :
     <input name="pass" type="password"/>
   </p>
   <p>Verify &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
      <input name="check" type="password"/>
   </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User" />
  </form>
</html>
```

**newuser.sh**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    #echo "Enter username..."                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    #read user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    #echo -e "Username :: $user \n Is this correct? [y,n]"                                                                                                                                                                                    

    #read y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    #if [[ $y == "y" ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    #       useradd -m $user                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    #else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    #       echo "Wrong username"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    #       exit                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    #fi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    usr=$1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    pass=$2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    useradd -m -s /usr/bin/nologin $usr                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    echo "$usr:$pass" | chpasswd
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please also revise your code to prevent Command Injection**

echo exec ("sudo /root/bin/newuser.sh ".$user." ".$pass."");

If any user submits a POST request like this:  `$_POST['user'] = '; rm -rf /;'` a big part of your server is deleted. Use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) php function to prevent shell injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your mail system to work with virtual accounts and give the web application user the rights to add and modify users, that would be way more secure than running web application under privileges of user with sudo-rights.